# Is [eclipse] being misused as a throw-in tag along with [java]? Should it be?

Tags: discussion, tags, tag-wiki

I have frequently noticed the 'eclipse' tag being used in questions which are actually nothing to do with the IDE (except the fact that the OP uses it to write java code).

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10104655/simple-java-class-to-download-the-file) is an example.

The tag wiki entry says nothing about whether using 'eclipse' in such questions is right or not. Actually it says:

> Within the Stack Overflow community, eclipse is synonymous with the
>   Java IDE.

On the other hand, another popular IDE tagged on SO 'xcode' clearly says:

> Consider what changes your question would require if you were using vi
>   to edit and make to build; if your question would remain unchanged,
>   then it is not an Xcode question, so you should not give your question
>   the xcode tag. Use the cocoa (Mac) and/or cocoa-touch (iOS) tags
>   instead.

Which I tend to like more.

Should the 'eclipse' tag wiki entry have a similar note? Should we proactively remove 'eclipse' tag from questions when it's actually being used purely in addition to 'java'?

Comment: Whoops, accidental flag. Sorry about that.

Comment: I updated the [eclipse tag wiki](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/eclipse/info) to reflect Oded's answer, since it appears to be the right thing to do.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> Should the 'eclipse' tag wiki entry have a similar note?

Yes, it should.

If a question is about the language and not the IDE, it shouldn't be tagged with the IDE as it is immaterial to the question.

> Should we proactively remove 'eclipse' tag from questions when it's actually being used purely in addition to 'java'?

Yes, it only adds noise and no value to such questions.

Comment: Right. I have updated the [eclipse tag wiki](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/eclipse/info) to reflect your answer.